# display error and highlight field on blur of the field and on submit of the page

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of text boxes in the page and I am trying to do some validations on blur of the field. If validation fails, error is displayed and the field is highlighted. 
This is working correctly. Now the scenario is, the user enters a wrong value and the field is highlighted. But he clicks the submit button. Now the field is 
not highlighted and also the error is not displayed in the form. When the form submits, if any error exists in the fields I want that field to be highlighted and the error also.
How is it possible?

Below is my code

```
var flag1 = true;
var indFlag = 0;

var validators = {
allowaplhawithaposonly:function(val) {
return /^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$/i.test(val);
},
allowaplhanumwithaposonly:function(val) {
    return /^[\w'\s]+$/i.test(val);
},
allownospace: function (val) {
    return !/\s/.test(val);
}
};

$('#submit_form .required').blur(function () {
var input = $(this);
var classReturn = true;
input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
input.removeClass('required_IE');

if(this.className) {
    var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    for(var p in classes) {
        if(classes[p] in validators) {
            classReturn = classReturn && validators[classes[p]] (input.val());
        }
    }
}
if(classReturn == false){
    input.removeClass('correct');
    input.addClass('required');
    var $msg = input.attr('title');
    input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
    flag1 = false;
    indFlag = 1;
}
else{
        if(indFlag != 1){//For checking if all the field validation is correct, then only flag1=true and form should submit
            flag1 = true;
    }
}

});

$('#submit_form').submit(function() {
 //It checks for some other conditions here

if(flag1)
    {
        returnValue = true;

    }
    else{
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
});
```

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks

Comment: can you create fiddle for same??

Comment: But in the fiddle its working correctly..means if error is there..on submit also that error is displayed..but in my code its not working...This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/55/